# Calling into native C/C++ code with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c++, c, xamarin.forms

I am in the process of evaluating whether to go all native with an app, that should run on Android and iOS and possibly UWP. I will have to call into native shared libraries/DLLs that use OpenSSL and probably GSoap. Is this possible with Xamarin.Forms? I have read there is something called Dependency Service to allow for native platform behaviour, but does this also encompass calling into custom C/C++ code? Should I better strive for native solutions for each platform instead if I now know beforehand, that native calls into C code are a necessity?

Any help appreciated,

-- 
Stefan